# Executing git commands via php over http

Tags: php, git, github, apache2, git-pull

OS - Ubuntu 14.04

I am working on deployment using GIT webhooks for it.

I have added the deployment keys to git repo and now I want to trigger the `git pull origin master` command when a push happens from my local repo.

This is the `test.php` file I call via browser:

```
<?php       
    //echo "THis is a test file on a test repo for testing the deploy functionality using github webhooks!!!!";
    echo exec('whoami');
    echo exec('sh -x /var/www/proj/test/git.sh');
?>
```

This is the `git.sh` shell file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/proj-dir/test
git pull origin master
```

When I run this on terminal using  `php test.php` I get the correct result as expected:

```
 ubuntu From github.com:repo/test
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 Already up-to-date.
```

`ubuntu` for `whoami` followed by the `git pull` output.

Now here's the issue when I call the same `http://example.com/test.php` via the browser it shows the user or `whoami` output as `www-data`, which is apache user, but I tried updating the permissions of the php file to execute and changing the user to `www-data` but did not work.
checked the apache logs and when I execute through the browser I get a permission error

```
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. + cd /var/www/proj/deploy-test + git pull origin master
```

Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

**What updates do I need to make so the file works via browser request?**

If I need to update the sudoers file what should be the updates?

**Update**
I added the `.ssh` keys to the `var/www/` dir as that is the home for apache user. But I still get the

```
git pull origin master
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

Also I added a line for the www-data user to be able to execute the sh file.

```
 www-data ALL=(anthony) NOPASSWD: /var/www/mysite/vendor/tmd/auto-git-pull/scripts/git-pull.sh
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/antriver/auto-git-pull) Still no luck
Updated the permissions for .git folder to www-data user

`sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/proj/test/.git`

Comment: You need to make sure that it's the correct user that asks for the pull. What user has pull rights from the repo? Seems you need to be ubuntu.

Comment: yes `ubuntu`,but I believe when accessing over `http` the apache user which is `www-data` needs to have permission to execute the script.After going through many posts I learnt I need to probably update the sudoers file for www-data to have correct permissions. PLease corect if my direction is wrong

Comment: Couldn't you just chmod the script so group/other has execution rights. And it seems your script is being executed.

Comment: Tried that,I swithced the user to `www-data` for the php and shell file,but did not work! I get www-data` as a result of whoami on browser that menas the user trying to run is www-data,right? Otherwise I might be under wrong assumptions

Comment: The user that executes git pull origin master needs to be ubuntu. Doesn't matter who executes the script.

Comment: so how to make ubuntu execute it? as over http it's www-data that is what I get as response of whoami. I have set the permissions to executable right now for any group.

Comment: Have the script switch to your ubuntu account before proceeding with git. Have ubuntu NOPASSWD set in `sudoers`.

Comment: @nicoX I got it working but I am not sure about the security implications involved. I had to change the permissions to `.git` folder to `www-data:www-data`. This works fine,but I tried adding `sudo ubuntu` in my shell file but it gives me `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`. I would request to add a solution with answer so that I can give a few points to you and close the thread.

Comment: You can add `ubuntu` and `www-data` to the same group, the chown your web root to allow the group access to it. As for your SSH key error, I assume that your SSH key for the ubuntu user (`ubuntu/~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) is the one that is allowed read access to your Git repository. You could add the www-data user a key and put that into the Git repository as well, or you could just make your PHP script run as the ubuntu user. There are ways to get around the error you saw. I have a similar deployment script which does some jobs as apache user, root and ec2-user on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be a PHP issue but a git config issue. Git is configured correctly for user `ubuntu` and not for user `www-data`.

You can try to make PHP run something as ubuntu, but that does not seem the easiest nor the correct. I would suggest configuring git correctly for the `www-data` user.

I suspect you can reproduce the issue by running on the terminal:

```
# become www-data user
sudo su www-data
# actions from your git.sh file
cd /var/www/proj-dir/test
git pull origin master
```

After verifying you do indeed have a reproduction scenario you can try to fix the problem for the `www-data` user.

Chances are there is a difference between the output of `git config --list` when run as either user. For more help on that score see https://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

It might als be that file permission / ownership differences are causing problems. To rule out, I suggest you use a `git clone ...` as user `www-data` to create a new clone and working copy in some other path in your filesystem. Then see again if the `git pull` now works as expected.

You may consider giving `www-data` its own working copy anyway (regardless of permission problems). This would also prevent having to deal with possible uncommitted changes in the working copy that result in merge problems. Handling these automatically / unattended from PHP / `git.sh` might be cumbersome.

The proposed workflow would then be: develop as `ubuntu` in your current working directory and `add`/`commit`/`push` your changes. Then have PHP do the `pull` as itself (as `www-data`).